# How to remove link around images using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Here is some HTML

```
<a href="some-link"><img src="image-src"></a>
```

How can I change it to

```
<img src="image-src">
```

using regex?

Thanks.

I tried to group it like

```
 (<a href=).don't know what to do here.(<img src=).don't know what to do here.(</a>)
```

After that I had no idea what to do. I am not good with regex.

Comment: Do you want this only for the `img` tag `href`, or all `href`s in the document? Also, for the sake of this forum, post your attempts, the expected result, and the achieved result.

Comment: I want this only for the `img` tag `href`. Please wait I am adding more details with my attempts. :)

Comment: Bad idea using regex for HTML tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/<a.*(<img.*">)<\/a>/
```

http://regexr.com/3dk2s

Use it like this:

```
preg_match('/<a.*(<img.*">)<\/a>/',$txt,$output);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c1d90d7ce516d007b181a2f9ae104e6ccaa54ea

Edit:
For replacing:
$txt = preg_replace('/)</a>/','$1',$txt);

Comment: Might I suggest going straight for [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @Bonatti Agreed, I didn't realized he wants to change, not extract them.